# How to remove activeadmin's batch action routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes, activeadmin

Using Rails 3.2.12, active_admin 0.6.2/0.6.3, I have disabled batch actions in my ActiveAdmin initializer:

```
config.batch_actions = false
```

However, `rake routes` shows batch action routes for all my registered ActiveAdmin controllers:

```
$ rake routes | grep batch
            batch_action_admin_admin_users POST     /admin/admin_users/batch_action(.:format)                                               admin/admin_users#batch_action
                batch_action_admin_members POST     /admin/members/batch_action(.:format)                                                   admin/members#batch_action
           batch_action_admin_sales_agents POST     /admin/sales_agents/batch_action(.:format)                                              admin/sales_agents#batch_action
               batch_action_admin_comments POST     /admin/comments/batch_action(.:format)                                                  admin/comments#batch_action
```

How do I remove these routes?

I tried to monkey-patch [this code](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/router.rb#L90) with:

```
post :batch_action if config.batch_actions
```

but it did not work.

EDITED: Answers below both make good points.  There is a [PR fixing this](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/pull/2944)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into the source code [here](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/batch_actions/resource_extension.rb#L17), I realized the appropriate monkey-patch would use `config.batch_actions_enabled?`.

Comment: Just want to note that Isaac submitted a patch fixing this and it's been merged into master. Thanks, Issac!

Answer (score 0):

I've analyzed sources of ActiveAdmin. Here's what I [found](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/router.rb#L90):

```
def resource_routes(config)
  # Some code here...
  case config
  when ::ActiveAdmin::Resource
    resources config.resource_name.route_key, :only => config.defined_actions do
      member do
        config.member_actions.each &build_action
      end

      collection do
        config.collection_actions.each &build_action
        post :batch_action
      end
    end
  # Code continues..
end
```

ActiveAdmin simply doesn't have configration option for that. It always generates batch routes.